# Rails 3 Routes/Render Missing Template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

So I have a simple Rails form that is sent to controller `admin`, action `checkLogin`. If the credentials are correct, redirect the user to a new view called `main.html.erb`.  Now in my controller I have literally tried everything, from `render 'main'`; to `redirect_to`. But I keep getting the following error:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template admin/activate with {
  :handlers=>[:rjs, :rhtml, :rxml, :builder, :erb],
  :formats=>[:js, :"application/ecmascript", :"application/x-ecmascript", :"*/*"],
  :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths "/home/xxx/xxx/xxx/rails/beta/app/views"
```

Is this a routing issue, or what?

Comment: Where is view `admin/activate` located?

Comment: it'd help to see the relevant parts of the form and of the controller

Answer (score 1):

Try `render :file => 'admin/main.html.erb'` to specify the exact file.

The problem is the render call is looking for a file that matches the name of your controller action, and it isn't finding it. So, specify the exact file and you should be ok.

FYI if you call `render 'main'` then it will try to render the view associated with your "main" action, which may not work if you don't have a "main" action.

Also, be sure you mean to render. If you DO have a main action and you want the stuff that's defined in that action to happen then you need to `redirect_to main_whatever_path`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you add the 'checkLogin' to routes. try this, in your routes.rb

```
resources :admin do
  member do
    get 'checkLogin'
  end
end
```

**NOTE : get 'checkLogin' might be post 'checkLogin' according to your case..

and inside your controller action 'checkLogin', render a partial

```
render :partial => 'main'
```